# Tokbox OpenTok client to call another client

Tags: webrtc, twilio, opentok, tokbox

I want to build an application where it is possible for one client to call another client using webRTC. I've started to look into webRTC providers and I've found Toxbox among others.

Is it possible, using TokBox OpenTok, for a client to actually make a call to another client (similar as a regular phone call)? From their docs and specifications it seems that it is only possible to create a "session" (a room in which participants meet and chat).

Am I missing something, or are they only providing sessions that people join/leave?

Twilio seem to offer what I need [here](https://www.twilio.com/video),
but I find it strange that I cannot find something similar at Tokbox.

Thanks,
Muff

Comment: Yes, It is possible to make a call from one client to another client like WhatsApp and other apps. You have to join with same session(Room).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You need to make the distinction between the type of API the platform exposes to what you can do with it.

While the OpenTok API is built around the concept of a room/session - you can easily use that concept to create a call. There are many openTok developers who do just that.

Twilio indeed offers the same capability - as are many others (a partial list can be found in this report - https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-paas-report/ - while the report is a paid one, the list is available on that page

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit on this, like how would you do this more specifically?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. When you dial, have your server randomly create a room name, or just do from-to as the room name - if 1234 calls 5678 then the room number will be 1234-5678. So 1234 enters the room and your service sends a push notification to 5678 indicating an "incoming call". When your app on 5678 answers - just have that user join the same room 1234-5678

Comment: yeah, when you say "push notification" do you mean the native Apple's Push Notifications?

And then when 5678 receives the push notification, the app just start to play a ring tone?

Comment: yes. that's the standard practice. don't use the standard push, but the VoIP one which is low latency - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

Comment: ok. But does it mean that I need to set up my own SIP gateway to interoperate with the OpenTok platform? 
Will this also work in a browser to app scenario?

Comment: No need for SIP or a SIP gateway.

Comment: Ok! Will it work cross platform tho? I mean, will it work in the following scenarios:
iOS app - Android app,
Browser - iOS App,
Browser - Android App,
iOS app - Browser,
Android app - browser?

Thanks a lot for your input so far!

Comment: Yes. IT will. My suggestion to you is to go read their documentation and play a bit with their samples.

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback.
I will continue to work my way through this.